# Reconnecting Bluetooth headset (hands free profile) after a phone call

Tags: android, bluetooth, phone-state-listener, bluetooth-sco

I am working on an Android app that plays audio through a Bluetooth headset, using the AudioManager's MODE_IN_CALL. I am able to detect the beginning and end of phone calls using a PhoneStateListener. So I can pause the audio when a call begins, but am having trouble reconnecting and resuming the audio after the phone call ends.

During the phone call the system operates in MODE_IN_CALL, but when the call ends there is about a four second delay before the system changes AudioManager's mode to MODE_NORMAL. So when I reconnect to the Bluetooth device after the phone call the system forces a disconnect after the delay of four or five seconds. I am currently using a timer to work around this issue, but I don't think it is a very good solution.

I want to know if there is some intent or system event that might be useful. Or any other solution to this issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It turns out that the audio focus request corresponds with the change in AudioManager mode. So I should be able to use the audio focus request event to trigger the BT reconnect.

Comment: When the audio focus request comes in the AudioManager reports that it is in MODE_NORMAL, but I am still having the issue described in my initial post.